# Split text into sentences by and/or

Tags: python, text, split, nlp, sentence

Text String:

```
text = ‘Turn left and take the door between stairs and elevator. Turn right to the corridor.’
```

Desire Output:

```
splitted_sentences= [‘turn left’, ‘take the door between stairs and elevator’, ‘turn right to the corridor’]
```

How can we split this text into sentences as shown in the splitted_sentences list by Python?

Comment: Welcome. You should read [tour] and [ask]. Please edit your attempt to solve this into your question and show the output. BTW StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service.

Comment: @j1-lee, the first one of my output sentences includes "and". That is not a typo. The problem is to discern which "and" is relevant or not for a boundary?

Comment: @j1-lee, because I try to convert the route descriptions into specific tasks of navigation. The first one is a specific task, but the second is related to "between". This is just an example of route descriptions. Each item should contain a task. It is sometimes useful to split these composite sentences into their component clauses for easier processing down the line. Sorry for the unclear question. I'm wondering what methods I should research about this.

Comment: @j1-lee, thanks :)

Comment: The only way I could think of to solve this is to take the words around "and", check them to see if they fit a criteria, and take the and out if it meets or fails that criteria. For example, you could put words like "take","turn"etc.etc. and if the and is next to them, take it out. Else, you could put words like "stairs","elevator",etc.etc. and not take out the and if it is between those.

Comment: @Agent Biscutt, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
"I write a code similar to the desired output."
import re
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
text = 'Turn left and take the door between stairs and elevator. Turn right to the corridor.'
text = text.lower()
text = text.replace("and",",")
split1 = re.split('; |[.] |[:]|, |\* |\n',text)
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens = [tokenizer.tokenize(word) for word in split1]
d = []
i = 0
for t in tokens:
    for a in t:
        if a == 'between':
            m = tokens.index(t)
while i < m:
    d.append(tokens[i])
    i +=1
d.append(tokens[m]+['and']+tokens[m+1])
n = m+2
while n < len(tokens):
    d.append(tokens[n])
    n +=1
print(d)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nioce job! Glad to see you figured it out.